# I can't stop wifi hotspot in android programming

Tags: wifi

i can start wifi hotspot in android programming. but i can't stop it.

i have 2 buttons in my app. and i can start wifi hotspot by 1 button.
i want to stop wifi hotspot by second button.

this is my java codes for start wifi hotspot:

```
wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                wmMethods = wifi.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
                for(Method method: wmMethods){
                  if(method.getName().equals("setWifiApEnabled")){
                    netConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
                    netConfig.SSID = wf;
                    netConfig.preSharedKey = wfp;
                    netConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
                    netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
                    netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
                    netConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK); 
                    netConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
                    netConfig.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
                    netConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
                    netConfig.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);  

                    try {
                      method.invoke(wifi, netConfig,true);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  }
                }}
```

please help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

try this code on second button to turn off your wifi hotspot...

```
 WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);

                if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                }

                WifiConfiguration apConfig = null;
                Method method = null;
                try {
                    method = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, Boolean.TYPE);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    method.invoke(wifiManager, apConfig, false);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```